# How to login right after registration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller, request

I am trying to register a new user into my system, and right after make the login automatically. How can I call another function in the same Controller and pass $request variables to it?

I did the var_dump, login function is getting data, the login is being made, but it's not redirecting to index (line 28)

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //var_dump($request->only('email', 'password'));
    
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
    
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->route('movie.index');       
    }

    return redirect()->route('login')->with([
        'error' => 'danger',
        'msg' => 'Error message',
    ]);
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $newUser = new User;
    $newUser->name = $request->name;
    $newUser->email = $request->email;
    $newUser->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $newUser->save();

    $this->login($request);
}
```

Comment: that method returns something and you are not doing anything with what it returns ... as a side note please do not put up pictures of code, code is text, there is no reason to use a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way is

```
Auth::login($newUser);
```

Then redirect to your page after login.